# VPNC on OpenWRT "no response from target"

Tags: openwrt, cisco-vpn-client, vpnc, lede

Im trying to connect to my university VPN using VPNC on a TP-Link Router with OpenWRT. I followed this [tutorial](http://randronov.blogspot.de/2017/06/lede-project-and-cisco-vpn-client-in-4.html). But I have two problems I cannot solve:

1. I don't have an IPSec ID or an IPSec secret, the Cisco Any Connect Client on my Windows machine does not need them and I can still connect. Do I need them in VPNC or can I leave them blank?
2. When I try to use the VPNC command manually in the routers console (`vpnc --no-detach --pid-file /var/run/vpnc-myVPN.pid --ifname vpn-myVPN --script /lib/netifd/vpnc-scripts`) and enter the gateway, username and password (leaving the IPSec ID and secret blank) I get the message: "no response from target". So I guess there are some firewall problems. I added the rules from the tutorial but when I run `iptables -L | grep vpn`, I don't see them. Not sure if that is the problem.